# IBM Digital Analytics - iOS - can't find framework

Tags: ios, frameworks, analytics

I'm following the instructions for integrating IBM's Digital Analytics (Core Metrics) into my iOS App.
https://developer.ibm.com/push/docs/ibm-mobile-push-notification/ibm-digital-analytics/

My project won't build complaining that in my AppDelegate.m it can't find:

```
#import <DAMod/DigitalAnalytics.h>
```

I've checked that DAMod.framework and EOCore.framework are listed under Link Binary with Libraries.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try removing and adding frameworks once again